# Is there a smooth map from the square to the deltoid?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, numerical-methods, manifolds, chebyshev-polynomials

Is there a $C^\infty$ map between a unit square in $\mathbb R^2$ and a deltoid like this one
[image: deltoid]
The deltoid is obtained by varying the angles $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$ in the equations
\begin{align}
x_2 &= \frac13 \left( \cos\left(\theta_1\right) + \cos\left(\theta_2\right) + \cos\left(\theta_1-\theta_2\right) \right)\\
x_2 &= \frac13 \left( \sin\left(\theta_1\right) - \sin\left(\theta_2\right) - \sin\left(\theta_1-\theta_2\right)\right)
\end{align}

Hence, the deltoid represents the range of the implicit map
$$
d: \left(\theta_1, \theta_2 \right) \mapsto \left(x_1,x_2\right)
$$
defined by the previous system of equations.
The question is to find a smooth map $f$ for which
$$
f\left(\left[0,1\right]^2\right) = d\left( \left[0,\pi\right]^2\right).
$$

I don't see anyway to obtain $f$.

Once I have $f$, I will use it to construct [bivariate chebyshev polynomial](http://hans.munthe-kaas.no/Chebyshev/Welcome_files/munthekaas09mcp.pdf) on a square.
An analytic expression for $f$ will be good, but as long as the derivative can be obtained numerically, it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, the [Riemann Mapping Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem). The square goes to the disc using [Schwarz-Christoffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping). There is such a mapping between the disc and deltoid, but there may not be published versions available.